# Selenium webdriver ruby version how to assert a webelement is not present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Is there anyway I can verify if an element is not present using *selenium* *webdriver* in ruby?

If i do

```
webdriver.find_element(:xpath, element)
```

But it throws an error if element is not present.I need to make sure that element is not present without throwing error.

I mean, is there a method like `assert_not` or `assert_element_not_present`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this two ways in Ruby. One is to follow @Saifur's solution, which would look like this:

```
# Returns true if no element is found
#
webdriver.find_elements(:xpath, element).empty?
```

The other way is to rescue the exception:

```
# Returns false if no element is found
#
webdriver.find_element(:xpath, element) rescue false
```

I'd suggest Saifur's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find_elements and do a count. the find_element method will return NoSuchElement(or similar) since the element's not found and that a legit exception. So, the test will not reach the assert. On the other hand, count `find_elements` will return 0 if none found and that's the easiest way to check. Sorry I am not very well versed on Ruby. But the equivalence C# looks like the following

```
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("Your Xpath "));
Assert.IsTrue(elements.Count != 0);
```